# Vanilla JS - Displaying Video Length (if statement)

Tags: javascript, math, html5-video, duration

I am looking to display a video length in the following of two formats:

if less than 59 seconds:

{no_of_sec}

if above 59 seconds:

{no_of_sec} : {no_of_sec}

At the moment this code:

```
document.getElementById("video2").duration
```

Returns the following value:

```
18.133313
```

I only need need it roundest to the nearest second then in the format above. Without overthinking it, I presume I need to round it. This can be done using Math.round() but it is when the number goes above 59 seconds is where I am struggle.

I plan to put this into an function which would loop through video elements with a class called:

```
.has--videoDuration
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you looking solution only for vanilla JavaScript? what about moment.js?

Answer (score 0):

Given the number of total seconds, you can compute the minute / second components as shown in the snippet below:

```js
var totalSeconds = 18.133313;

var minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
var seconds = Math.floor(totalSeconds % 60);

alert(minutes + ':' + seconds);
```

Comment: Hi @w0lf does this mean that if totalSeconds was 18.5111 it would return as 18?

Comment: @Neil Yes, in that case `minutes` would be `0` and `seconds` would be `18`.

Comment: I guess its better to bring the time down than round it up. Do you have a recommendation on code for using this in a for each loop or jQuery .each?

Comment: @Neil This code is independent from jQuery and calls to `.each`. Simply wrap this in a function and call it however you want.

Comment: The original contained a document.getElementById("video2") so it would only work on this id. I would have to break the cardinal sin of re-using ids.. :(

Comment: Find another way to reference the DOM element (like class, for example). Anyway, this is a bit off-topic as far as the original question is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon your code:

```
var duration = Math.round(document.getElementById("video2").duration);
var minutes = ~~(duration / 60); // 1 minute every 60 seconds
var seconds = duration - 60 * minutes; // Remaining seconds
var timeString = minutes ? (minutes + ':' + seconds) : seconds;
```

I guess the `timeString` is what you are looking for.

BTW: I would rather use `Math.floor` for the duration (or `~~`), but the exact choice of duration normalization is independent of the rest.

Comment: Hi @florian I am not familiar with ~~ what does this define / invoke?

Comment: It's basically a short form of `Math.floor` - the `~` operator is a bitwise-not, which only operates on integers internally. Therefore the value will be casted to a number (in our case it is already a number) and converted to an integer (which we want). However, the value is now negated. Now we do another bitwise-not to restore the original (integer) value. In a way the `~~` is therefore equivalent to `(int)` casts in type-based PL. It works exactly like `Math.floor` for positive integers, but like `Math.ceil` for negative ones. Thus it truncates the value.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up!